# Transparent fuzziness

Tags: transparency

I'm having a problem with the Alpha transparency on my PNGs.

I'm using planes as a treeline and faking some depth with some that are a little closer up. If you look at the picture provided there is almost like a fuzz that surrounds the tree that's closer up than. I'm not sure what's causing it, the image itself is clean around the outside and even has a few holes in the middle that seem to get some fuzz in them. I can't seem to find any settings to change that would fix this issue.

Any ideas why there's almost like a fuzzy stroke in the alpha areas of my pictures?

Thanks!

[image: Trees]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of white edge artifacts when using alpha texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67704/how-to-get-rid-of-white-edge-artifacts-when-using-alpha-texture)

Comment: Hi Bryan. Is that a render or the 3D view in material mode?